# Save regex to database in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to regex value to mysql database using PHP:

Regex is added via php form:

```
/^(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
```

it gets automatically converted to :

```
/^(?:http://|https://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtu.be/|youtube.com/(?:embed/|v/|watch?v=|watch?.+&v=))((w|-){11})(?:S+)?$/
```

Why it isn't same as what we have in database?

Comment: probably because you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: what to do if i want to save this

Comment: learn how to write proper queries so you don't get bitten by injection attacks. The exact same techniques that prevent injection attacks would allow your regex to get into the database properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL PHP Escape String '\' - Why is it not saved in the database with the backslash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14795811)

Comment: If you want to input \ into the database, you have to use two backslashes, \\, which translates to a literal \. So, you could replace all \\ with \\\\ (replacing all  literal \ with literal \\\).

Also, you seem to be prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so make sure to prevent against that, or someone could run a query to destroy your entire database without having access to the database